# Find $\iint_T{\frac{1}{2}xy\,dx\,dy}$ where T is the triangle with vertices at (1, 0), (3,2) and (5,0)

Tags: calculus, integration

Please help me point out where I've gone wrong...

I got the limits: $\int_{x-1}^2\int_1^5\frac{1}{2}xy\,dx\,dy$

Then changed the order of integration: $\int_1^5\int_{x-1}^2\frac{1}{2}xy\,dy\,dx$

Integrating I got: $\int_5^1({\frac{1}{4}xy^2})^2_{x-1}\,dx$

Then: $\int_5^1(\frac{x^3-2x-3x}{4})\,dy$

And ended up with: $(\frac{x^4}{16}-\frac{5x^2}{8})^5_1$

This doesn't seem right to me.

Have I gone wrong right from the start?

Thanks very much for your help!

Sam

Comment: I've missed out a lot of the algebra that I did to get to this point, so if that's where I'm going wrong, apologies! Thanks!

Comment: While changing the order of integration, you need to change the upper and lower limits accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the triangle is bounded by the lines $y=x-1, y=5-x$, and $y=0$, we get

$\displaystyle\int\int_{T}\frac{1}{2}xy\;dA=\int_0^2\int_{y+1}^{5-y}\frac{1}{2}xy\;dxdy=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^2\left[x^2y\right]_{y+1}^{5-y} \;dy=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^2y((5-y)^2-(y+1)^2)dy$

$\displaystyle=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^2(24y-12y^2)dy=\int_0^2(6y-3y^2)dy=[3y^2-y^3]_0^2=4$.

---

Alternatively, you can use that

$\displaystyle\int\int_{T}\frac{1}{2}xy\;dA=\int_1^3\int_0^{x-1}\frac{1}{2}xy\;dydx+\int_3^5\int_0^{5-x}\frac{1}{2}xy\;dydx=\frac{5}{3}+\frac{7}{3}=4$.

Answer (score 1):

Better split the integral like so:
$$\begin{gathered}
  \int\limits_1^3 {\int\limits_0^{x - 1} {(\frac{1}{2}xydydx)} }  + \int\limits_3^5 {\int\limits_{ - x + 1}^0 {(\frac{1}{2}xydydx)} }  \hfill \\
   = \int\limits_1^3 {x{{(x - 1)}^2}dx}  + \int\limits_3^5 {x{{( - x + 1)}^2}dx}  \hfill \\
   = \int\limits_1^3 {({x^3} - 2{x^2} + x)dx}  + \int\limits_3^5 {({x^3} - 2{x^2} + x)dx}  \hfill \\
   = \int\limits_1^5 {({x^3} - 2{x^2} + x)dx}  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}{4}{5^4} - \frac{2}{3}{5^3} + \frac{1}{2}{5^2} - (\frac{1}{4} - \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{2}) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$